# What are consequences of applying glyphosate in vicinity of fruit trees?

Tags: weed-control, fruits

What are consequences of applying glyphosate on weeds in vicinity of fruit trees? Specifically, in my case, fruits are sour cherry, pear, and walnut.

Is there any posibility that the fruit would contain harmful substances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you follow the instructions there should be no adverse consequences. When properly used glyphosate is a safe, effective weedkiller.